# NSURLSession in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to write a simple NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL using Swift 2.0. For some reason I am getting weird errors.

[image]

What am I missing since Swift is not helping me?

UPDATE: If I do not call resume() then I get the following exception:

[image]

Comment: Notice that you have extra ) before .resume. Check your braces carefully.

Comment: You should not share code through screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call `resume` directly, you have to pass in the completion block with the function parameter list, that means inside of the brackets. Otherwise, Swift assumes that you want to call `resume` on the block itself. The below snippet compiles fine with Swift 2 in Xcode 7 beta 5.

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "")!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    print("sss")
}).resume()
```

If you want to use the shorthand form of specifying the completion block after the closing `)`, you need two statements.

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "")!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    print("sss")
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Duh!! I was missing sharedSession. I am such a idiot :) Thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score -1):

remove the extra `).resume()`. What should this be for?

Comment: .resume is to execute the actual request!!

Comment: then just call `session.resume()` instead

Comment: I believe Swift 2.0 has much bigger issues. I am doing this in Playground and Swift 2.0 is simply blowing up on everywhere.

Comment: I like working with swift 2 more and more already. For me it has way less issues than in the beginning of swift 1